# MATLAB's ode45 not dealing with initial conditions well [RESOLVED]

Tags: matlab, electromagnetism, differential-equations

*Concern highlighted in yellow

*Solution at bottom

I have a differential equation to solve for the motion of an electron:

$$
\frac{d^2v}{dt^2} = \frac{1}{\gamma^6}\left( \frac{eE}{\tau m} - \left( \frac{\gamma}{\tau} \frac{dv}{dt} + \frac{\gamma^3}{\tau c^2} v^2 \frac{dv}{dt} + 6\frac{\gamma^8}{c^2} v \left( \frac{dv}{dt} \right)^2\right) \right)
$$

$$ 
\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\\
e = 1.6\times 10^{-19}\\
E = 10^6\\
\tau = 6\times 10^{-24}\\
m = 9.1\times 10^{-31}\\
c = 3\times10^8
$$

With initial conditions
$$v(0) = 0$$
$$\frac{dv}{dt}\biggr\rvert_0 = Ee/m \approx 6\times 10^{-4}$$

But I heard that it is good practice to make everything dimensionless so that your computer can handle things nicely, so I introduced some dimensionless variables:

$$
T = t/\tau\\
V = v/c\\
\varepsilon = \frac{\tau e}{cm} E
$$

This gets me to the final form:

$$
\frac{d^2V}{dT^2} = \frac{1}{\gamma^6}\left( \varepsilon - \left( \gamma \frac{dV}{dT} + \gamma^3 V^2 \frac{dV}{dT} + 6\gamma^8 V \left( \frac{dV}{dT} \right) ^2 \right)\right)
$$

With initial conditions

$$
V(0) = 0\\
\frac{dV}{dT}\biggr\rvert_0 = \varepsilon \approx 4\times 10^{-15}
$$

> I am using MATLAB's ode45 to solve this, but I do not think it can handle such small initial conditions. The plot should rapidly asymptote to 1, but I can only get that to happen with fairly large initial conditions:

### Initial acceleration equal to $\varepsilon$

[image]

### Initial acceleration equal to $10$

[image]

I can't tell what the issue is, but I'll post my code - it's not very long:

### Script for the Differential Equation

```matlab
function dv2dt = emDeq(t, v)
mu = 4*pi*10^(-7);
c = physconst('LightSpeed');
e = 1.6022e-19;
m = 9.1094e-31;
tau = mu*e^2/(6*pi*m*c);

E = (10^6)*(tau*e)/(c*m);
% E = 1e6;

gam = (1 - v(1)^2)^(-1/2);

dv2dt = [v(2); (gam^(-6))*( E  - ( gam*v(2) + (gam^3)*(v(1))^2*v(2) + 6*(gam^8)*v(1)*(v(2))^2 ) )];

end
```

### Script for Plotting

```matlab
mu = 4*pi*10^(-7);
c = physconst('LightSpeed');
e = 1.6022e-19;
m = 9.1094e-31;
tau = (mu*e^2)/(6*pi*m*c);
E = (10^6)*(tau*e)/(c*m);
% E = 1e6;

v0 = 0;
a0 = E;
% a0 = E*e/m;
[t, v] = ode45(@emDeq, [0, 10], [v0, a0]);
figure('Color', 'w')
plot(t, v(:,1));
title('V vs T'); xlabel('T'); ylabel('V');
```

### Solution

I needed to redefine length scales and time scales, as well as use either ode15s or ode23s.

1 time step is $\tau$s, one length step is $10^{-15}$m, one voltage step is $10^{-10}$. This got me a reasonable $\epsilon$ to work with. Plots below. Thanks to everyone who helped out!

[image]

Comment: You desperately need to either change units or nondimensionalize your problem. The magnitudes on the constants and dependent variable are likely causing trouble. I would also recommend you use a stiff solver like ode15s just to be sure that these constants are not causing stability issues that can be easily solved

Comment: @whpowell96 I nondimensionalized it, but the magnitude issues seemed to have gotten compressed to a single constant, $\varepsilon$, which appears in the initial conditions as well as the differential equation. I am not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: Maybe you should try rescaling the time like $s=\varepsilon^\alpha T$, $U = \varepsilon^\beta V$. Rewrite the equation in terms of $U$ and $s$ then you can play around with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to fix to rescale the initial condition to your liking. It may also be possible to choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so it makes the actual differential equation better conditioned as well. Again, I would suggest using ode15s just in case

Comment: I worked with your suggestion and I got somewhere hopeful! I will post the resolved version.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to rescale everything back in the end to make sure your units are correct

Comment: @MurderOfCrows You can post your solution as an answer, explaining that rescaling space and time made computations be safer from numerical inaccuracies. After a week or so, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with initial conditions is more related with the sum of very small numbers with other that are only small (I suspect the problem resides in terms like `gam^8`, since `gam` is small). The resulting numeric inaccuracy will bring problems.

I've played around with other initial conditions and integration times and in `octave` (that is similar but not equal to `matlab`), the integration seems to work initially for $E=10^8$ but not for $E=10^7$, although I observed numeric instabilities for $t>10$. That numeric instability was observed up to $E=10^{16}$ but not for $E=10^{17}$.

Although it does not solve your problem in this case, sometimes changing the order of the parcels may help in reducing the numeric inaccuracy problems, e.g., something like:

```
dv2dt = [v(2); -(gam^(-6))*( 6*(gam^8)*v(1)*(v(2))^2 + (gam^3)*(v(1))^2*v(2) + gam*v(2) - E )];
```

Comment: ```gam``` is at least 1 and blows up fairly quickly, so I am not sure if that is the issue. Though relative sizes may be, so perhaps I need to use a more precise ode solver. Do you know of any?

Comment: @MurderOfCrows I'm not sure if your problem is stiff or not, but perhaps `ode15s`.